# `mprotect` fails after many invocations

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel

I invoke `mprotect` frequently in my program, and I find the program fails after a while. I guess it is due to too many `mprotect` calls, So I wrote a test to verify:

```
#define pagesize 4096
int main(){
  while(1){
     buffer = memalign(pagesize, 4 * pagesize);// allocate some buffer
     mprotect(buffer, pagesize, PROT_NONE)// make the first page inaccessible
  }
}
```

After around 30 thousand iterations, mprotect returns -1, regardless of the size of the buffer.

Can anybody explain why and how to resolve it? My guess is mprogtect consumes kernel resources and there is some constraint for each process, but not sure.

Comment: How much ram your machine has? May the problem be with allocation and not with protection?

Comment: In general, you should follow the usual approach when debugging such problems: recompile the kernel with whatever debugging options necessary enabled (such as CONFIG_DEBUG_VM or CONFIG_DEBUG_PAGEALLOC or whatever) and then monitor the `dmesg` output closely, possibly on remote machine using serial port console.

Comment: @oakad I have 4G ram on my 32-bit ubuntu. 30K * 4K * 4 = 480M. So it should not be due the constraint of either virtual address space in user-space or RAM, right?

Comment: Never hurts to ask. Do you get any complaints in `dmesg` prior to program hanging?

Comment: @oakad Thank you. But we got nothing in dmesg.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the limit in `/proc/sys/vm/max_map_count`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, there's a kernel parameter controlling the number of distinct mappings a process can have, available at `/proc/sys/vm/max_map_count`. The typical default number of mappings on most distros is 64k - consistent with `mprotect` failing at around 30k iterations (one mapping per `memalign`, another per `mprotect` + some normal system mappings). Increasing that limit will allow you to allocate and protect more memory areas.

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot. And this [link](https://my.vertica.com/docs/4.1/HTML/Master/12962.htm) tells how to increase the limit max_map_count temporarily or permanently.

Comment: @Infinite the link is now dead